# How to setup virtual hosts in xampp with same parent server alias or name

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost

I want to set up 2 virtual hosts on my local xampp environment, I have two different WordPress websites with URLs

**test.com** and
**test.com/blog**

Now I want to set up vhosts for local like
**test.local** and
**test.local/blog**

test.local works but test.local/blog redirects to test.local's 404 page

xampp vhosts configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/xampp/htdocs/test.com"
    ServerName test.local
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.local/blog
    DocumentRoot "/xampp/htdocs/blog-test.com"
 </VirtualHost>
```

hosts file setup:

```
127.0.0.1       test.local
127.0.0.1       test.local/blog
```

Answer (score 1):

ServerName can be used for 2 or more different domains when configuring virtual hosts.

You do not have different domains.

test.com and test.com/blog are the same domain.

Similarly

test.local and test.local/blog are the same domain